# Suddenly no Windows partition will boot, yet all my Linux partitions do

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot

I have 5 OS to choose from in multi-boot computer. The SSD has a Linux partition and a Win 10 partition. A HDD has 2 Windows 7 partitions and 1 Linux partition.

Up until a week ago all the OSs booted just fine. But the case fans were running slow or sometimes not at all, and the AMD CPU fan was also running slow.

So I replaced **all** the fans. Instead of the stock AMD fan I bought an upgrade one. The case fans are also upgrade quality.

After replacing the fans, no Windows OS will boot. It starts with the Windows graphics working but then suddenly reboots the computer. I have only used 1 of the Win 7 partitions recently and it was just prior to replacing the fans. I have not used the other Win 7 or the Win 10 in quite a while. I mostly use the Linux from the SSD.

So I'm thinking there has to be some relation between the fan replacement and the boot failures. When the boot failure occurs it sets many of my NTFS partitions to READ ONLY because a check disk is triggered. Don't know why it chooses the ones it does though.

I can attach a `ntbtlog` or a `minidump` or any other file if anyone reads this and is interested. I tried all manner of debug boot, low-res boot, safe boot, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue and this is even more likely to be since you did work on the PC parts. I'd inspect the internals of the PC, disconnect cables and whatnot and carefully reseat them. I suspect the new fans are not power hungry, but if balance PSU <> consumers was already critical and they consume slightly more, they might be the straws that break the camel's back.

Comment: *some relation between the fan replacement and the boot failures* - highly unlikely, unless you did something else while the power was off, like a BIOS upgrade, a CMOS reset.

Comment: Considering that the Linux OSs boot no problem is what confuses me.  And that the Windows OSs that I hadn't used in quite a while were affected points to some kind of hardware issue.  However, could I have run into some sort of Linux malware?